# Overwrite Mixin with updated attributes in Sass

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to overwrite a mixin with attributes that should take the place of the mixin. The output CSS file creates 2 classes instead of merging into one.

```
@mixin links($link-color, $hover-color, $visited-color){
& {
    color: $link-color;
    display: inline-block;

    &:visited {
        color: $visited-color;
    }

    &:hover {
        color: $hover-color;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}

.links a{
   @include links(red, green, black);
   display: block;
}
```

CSS Expected Output:

```
.links a{
  color: red;
  display: block;
}

.links a:visited {
  color: black;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

Actual Output:

```
.links a{
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.links a{
  display: block;
}

.links a:visited {
  color: black;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

As you can see it creates 2 of the same class instead of having the "display: block" overwrite what is in the mixin. Is there a way to output it so that the CSS file updates with the overwritten attribute? I tried @content as well and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` wrapper in your mixin is unnecessary, since when you include it, it is already within the selector. And it's also the reason why the selector is duplicated. It is not possible to get the exact output you want, but you can still have you mixin properties overriding the existing properties as long as you include it after them:

```scss
@mixin links($link-color, $hover-color, $visited-color) {
  color: $link-color;
  display: inline-block;

  &:visited {
    color: $visited-color;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: $hover-color;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}

.links a {
  display: block;
  @include links(red, green, black);
}
```

It will output as:

```scss
.links a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block; // Will override the first `display` property
}

.links a:visited {
  color: black;
}

.links a:hover {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```